# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in nodejs code execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

My current nodejs version is: 8.9.1

I'm trying to execute my code but i'm always having this error, tried to fix it but have always the same error :

> (node:38) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of
>   undefined (node:38) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

Here it is my code:

```
"use strict";
const rp = require("request-promise-native");
module.exports = async function (context) {
    const stringBody = JSON.stringify(context.request.body);
    const body = JSON.parse(stringBody);
    const location = body.location;
    if (!location) {
        return {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                text: "You must provide a location."
            }
        };
    }
    try {
        const response = await rp(`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="${location}") and u="c"&format=json`);
        const condition = JSON.parse(response).query.results.channel.item.condition;
        const text = condition.text;
        const temperature = condition.temp;
        return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                text: `It is ${temperature} celsius degrees in ${location} and ${text}`
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: e
        };
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The inner error is telling you that whatever object "body" is a property of is undefined at the time you're trying to retrieve the body property. In this scenario, my guess is that when you try to do `JSON.stringify(context.request.body)`, context.request is undefined.

You can read more about the outer error here - https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in this case what can you suggest for me , because i did tried so many changes but actually get stuck always in the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that on this line of code:

```
const stringBody = JSON.stringify(context.request.body);
```

`context.request` is apparently `undefined` which means that `context.request.body` throws an exception.  Since `context` is coming from the caller, this means that the caller is not passing you what you expect.  This synchronous exception inside an `async` function causes that function to immediately return a rejected promise.

And, apparently your caller is not handling a rejected promise so you then get the warning about an unhandled rejected promise.

There are multiple things you can do to fix:

1. Fix the caller so it is always passing an appropriate context variable.
2. Fix the caller so it has a handler for a rejected promise
3. Fix this function so that it catches the exception and handles it like your other rejections (by returning the 500 status).

Here's the fix for #3:

```
"use strict";
const rp = require("request-promise-native");
module.exports = async function (context) {
    try {
        const stringBody = JSON.stringify(context.request.body);
        const body = JSON.parse(stringBody);
        const location = body.location;
        if (!location) {
            return {
                status: 400,
                body: {
                    text: "You must provide a location."
                }
            };
        }
        const response = await rp(`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="${location}") and u="c"&format=json`);
        const condition = JSON.parse(response).query.results.channel.item.condition;
        const text = condition.text;
        const temperature = condition.temp;
        return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                text: `It is ${temperature} celsius degrees in ${location} and ${text}`
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: e
        };
    }
}
```

This fix for #3 is good defensive programming.  It probably removes the need for #2 because this function probably can't ever reject its promise.

But, to make your program work as expected, you probably need to figure out why the `context` being passed in does not contain `context.request` like you expect.  That's probably the real source of the issue.

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your answer, actually i tried something when i replaced    const stringBody = JSON.stringify(context.request.body); with  const stringBody = JSON.stringify(context); i have no more that error but my code is giving me no result

Comment: @angelpretty - You can't just try things like that.  Go to the calling code and study it and find out why `context.request` isn't what you expect it to be.  You need to fully understand what the calling code is doing to make a proper fix.  We can't help you with that because you haven't shown any of the calling code.